# Apache Camel & Artemis, consume 1 message at a time

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I have a requirement of reading only one message from artemis queue in the camel route . Once the message is processed , I need to read the next message in the queue. But currently on deployment of the app - it consumes all the messages

I tried all artemis attributes,  but nothing works

Comment: Did you try consumerWindowSize: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/flow-control.html

Comment: Hi. Thanks . It works after adding slow consumers. But in case of 2 consumers,  how it works

Answer (score 0):

> I have a requirement of reading only one message from artemis queue in the camel route . Once the message is processed , I need to read the next message in the queue.

This is the default behavior with camel-jms, camel-amqp and camel-activemq components. The default value for `concurrentConsumers` option is 1 and `asyncConsumer` is false by default. They're however polling-consumers so they will read the next message immediately after they've finished processing the current.

This is fairly easy to demonstrate by having one route that publishes 2 or more messages to a queue then another route that consumes messages from a route but includes a delay.

Following should only read 1 message from queue every 3 seconds.

```java
from("timer:writeTimer?period=1000")
    .routeId("toTestQueue")
    .setBody().constant("first message")
    .to("jms:queue:testqueue")
    .setBody().constant("another message")
    .to("jms:queue:testqueue")
;

from("jms:queue:testqueue")
    .routeId("readMessages")
    .log("received message: ${body}")
    .delay(3000)
;
```

If you want more control when message(s) get read you can use [Poll Enrich](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html) to read 1 message from queue at any point.

```java
from("timer:writeTimer?period=1000")
    .routeId("toTestQueue")
    .setBody().constant("hello artemis")
    .to("jms:queue:testqueue")
;

from("timer:readTimer?period=10000")
    .routeId("readMessages")
    .setProperty("done").constant(false)
    .log("Reading messages from queue.")
    .loopDoWhile(exchangeProperty("done").isEqualTo(false))
        // Reads message from queue, returns null if there no new messages. 
        .pollEnrich("jms:queue:testqueue", 1000)
        .choice().when(body().isNotNull())
            .log("Message ${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}:  ${body}" )
        .otherwise()
            //Queue was empty, exit the loop
            .setProperty("done").constant(true)
        .end()
    .end()
    .log("Finished reading messages from queue.")
;
```

You could replace the timer route from readMessages route with for example direct:readMessageFromQueue and use ProducerTemplate to active the route at any time to consume 1 message from the queue.